# Добавление SSL для поддомена с Let's Encrypt

Tags: ubuntu, letsencrypt

У меня есть домен `example.com`, который защищён с помощью Let's Encrypt по SSL. А теперь я хочу добавить к своему домену ещё и несколько поддоменов. Например, `mail.example.com` и `search.example.com`. Как мне это сделать?

Comment: Выписать для каждого свой сертификат. Можно, конечно, выписать один на все, но обычно в этом нет никакого смысла.

Answer (score 3):

У Letsencrypt в [FAQ](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/faq/) написано что у них пока нет в планах выпускать wildcard сертификаты (т.е. для *.example.com).

> Will Let’s Encrypt issue wildcard certificates?
>
> We currently have no plans to do so, but it is a possibility in the
>   future. Hopefully wildcards aren’t necessary for the vast majority of
>   our potential subscribers because it should be easy to get and manage
>   certificates for all subdomains.

Поэтому можно либо [получать сертификат](https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#getting-certificates-and-choosing-plugins) для каждого поддомена тем же самым способом, которым был получен сертификат для основного, либо создать сертификат сразу для нескольких доменных имён.

Например, в [документации](https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#webroot) для плагина `webroot` есть пример:

```
certbot certonly --webroot \
    -w /var/www/example/ -d www.example.com -d example.com \
    -w /var/www/other -d other.example.net -d another.other.example.net
```

Этой командой можно создать один сертификат сразу для нескольких доменов. Здесь, `/var/www/example/` - это webroot для доменов `www.example.com` и `example.com`, а `/var/www/other` - для `other.example.net` и `another.other.example.net`

Но у LetsEncrypt есть [ограничения](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/rate-limits/) на использования одного сертификата для нескольких доменных имён. Можно создать один сертификат для максимум 100 доменов.

Добавить поддомены к существующему сертификату не получится. Нужно сначала [удалить сертификат](https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#revoking-certificates) (см. команды `revoke` и `delete`), а затем создать новый сертификат сразу для нескольких доменов

Comment: wildcard в данном случае не нужен, Let's Encrypt позволяет сделать один сертификат на сотню поддоменов сразу

Comment: @andreymal а дайте ссылку, пожалуйста, где про это написано

Comment: По вашей же ссылке на FAQ ровно на один вопрос выше :D Правда, сотня там не упоминается, сейчас поищу где видел

Comment: Нашёл, про сотню рядышком https://letsencrypt.org/docs/rate-limits/ — «If you have a lot of subdomains, you may want to combine them into a *single* certificate, up to a limit of **100 Names per Certificate**.»

Comment: @andreymal спасибо за ссылку, я нашёл всю остальную документацию и обновил ответ

Answer (score 0):

Получать сертификат лучше с помощью одного из рекомендованных клиентов. Моим выбором стал GetSSL. Это простой bash скрипт, который умеет сам себя обновлять. При работе использует CLI openssl, и значит нет жесткой привязки к версии.

GetSSL автоматизирует процесс получения и продления сертификата с помощью нескольких команд. Например, чтобы получить сертификат для домена domain.tld:

```
srv ~ # getssl -c domain.tld
creating main config file /root/.getssl/getssl.cfg
Making domain directory - /root/.getssl/domain.tld
creating domain config file in /root/.getssl/domain.tld/getssl.cfg
srv ~ # getssl domain.tld
```

Первая команда добавляет домен в список для получения (выполняется единожды), вторая - для получения сертификата.

В случае поддоменов (в том числе www) в файле конфигурации нужно просто их перечислить через запятую:

```
# Additional domains - this could be multiple domains / subdomains in a comma separated list
# Note: this is Additional domains - so should not include the primary domain.
SANS=www.example.com,mail.example.com,search.example.com,
```

В этой статье можно подробнее узнать о процессе п[олучения сертификата с помощью GetSSL.](https://www.influunt.ru/getting-started-with-lets-encrypt)

Answer (score 0):

### Инструкция для Apache

Допустим, что виртуальные хосты лежат по следующему пути:

```
/home/ubuntu/.config/virtual-hosts.conf
```

и представляют собой следующее:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/example.com
  <Directory /home/ubuntu/example.com>
    Require all granted
    AllowOverride all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

  <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test.example.com
    DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/test.example.com
    <Directory /home/ubuntu/test.example.com>
      Require all granted
      AllowOverride all
    </Directory>
  </VirtualHost>
```

---

Добавляем сертификат для домена `example.com`:

```
sudo certbot --apache -d example.com
```

Что получаем в результате?

---

**1.** В `/home/ubuntu/.config` Certbot создаст файл `virtual-hosts-le-ssl.conf` со следующим содержимым:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

  <VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/example.com
    <Directory /home/ubuntu/example.com>
      Require all granted
      AllowOverride all
    </Directory>
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
  </VirtualHost>

</IfModule>
```

**2.** В `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` Certbot создаст ссылку на вышеуказанный файл:

```
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled
├── 000-default.conf -> ../sites-available/000-default.conf
└── virtual-hosts-le-ssl.conf -> /home/ubuntu/.config/virtual-hosts-le-ssl.conf
```

**3.** Если мы ответили `2` на вопрос перенаправлять ли трафик с `http` на `https`, то содержимое файла `/home/ubuntu/.config/virtual-hosts.conf` станет следующим (добавится редирект):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/example.com
  <Directory /home/ubuntu/example.com>
    Require all granted
    AllowOverride all
  </Directory>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com
  RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

  <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test.example.com
    DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/test.example.com
    <Directory /home/ubuntu/test.example.com>
      Require all granted
      AllowOverride all
    </Directory>
  </VirtualHost>
```

---

Добавляем сертификат для поддомена `test.example.com`:

```
sudo certbot --apache -d test.example.com
```

Что делаем дальше?

---

<s>Или я просто не знаю, что подразумевает Certbot под своими действиями (так как документацию не читал), или это баг; в любом случае, если оставить всё по дефолту, то ничего не работает (по крайней мере у меня), так как он (Certbot) делает какой-то трэш в конфигурационных файлах.</s>

**1.** Заменяем содержимое файла `/home/ubuntu/.config/virtual-hosts-le-ssl.conf` на это:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

  <VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/example.com
    <Directory /home/ubuntu/example.com>
      Require all granted
      AllowOverride all
    </Directory>
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
  </VirtualHost>

  <VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName test.example.com
    DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/test.example.com
    <Directory /home/ubuntu/test.example.com>
      Require all granted
      AllowOverride all
    </Directory>
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.example.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.example.com/privkey.pem
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
  </VirtualHost>

</IfModule>
```

**2.** Заменяем содержимое файла `/home/ubuntu/.config/virtual-hosts.conf` на это:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/example.com
  <Directory /home/ubuntu/example.com>
    Require all granted
    AllowOverride all
  </Directory>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com
  RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

  <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test.example.com
    DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/test.example.com
    <Directory /home/ubuntu/test.example.com>
      Require all granted
      AllowOverride all
    </Directory>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =test.example.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
  </VirtualHost>
```

---

Все вышеописаные действия делал для своего сервера на момент написания ответа.